# What is the animated small yellow disk In Mdriven Designer Viewmodels for?

Tags: mdriven

What is the small animated yellow disk In Mdriven Designer Viewmodels for?
It moves so fast and is so feint, I don't know what it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a viewmodel grows in size - the yellow indicator will help you to associate the connection between a placed UI-widget and the expression that defines it.

When a viewmodel is small this is usually not a problem that needs solving, but as the requirements and the UI grows it is helpful:
[image]

Comment: On my screen the yellow indicator doesn't look like your screenshot. I just get a small circle that moves across the page so fast I can't follow it. It has no meaning other than me being slightly aware that "something" is happening.